# How to "simplify" an entire project in order to import it in another?

Tags: mesh, rigging, import, cloth-simulation

I have a character created in Blender which consists of a complexity of rigging, material, clothing and control bones.

I have to import it into another project, but as the first project is almost an controlled accident, I am wondering if there would be a technique to do a kind of "compiling" in order to make it simple to manipulate in the other project.

In time, this project works as a kind of "statue", which doesn't need new clothing simulations, new bone poses and etc. Any help would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're searching for [linking](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html) objects into another scenes; thus you'll have a library (.blend with your rigged object) and scene (.blend with all the assets setup for render). [Proxy objects](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html#proxy-objects) should help to rig linked object in the scene file without switching to library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're a beginner (it seems) you can:
- Save your .blend fila with another name - select your model - got to the modifiers tab in the properties window and press the "apply" button on all the modifiers you don't need (armature, cloth, etc.) Start applying the modifiers from the upper (first calculated) to the lower (last).
Then delete the armature and everything you don't need, save the new file, close it and then reopen. - Import you model from this new file.